# Can't load Gmail but only at certain times of day (502 error)

Tags: networking, dns, gmail, gateway

Not sure if this is the right place to post this but I am at my wit's end. For the last several days, *but only during certain times* (usually in the afternoon Pacific time), my computer refuses to connect to `mail.google.com`, returning a 502 error regardless of browser. So yesterday afternoon I couldn't connect, this morning was fine, and now it's down again.

I have no VPNs or traffic capturing services running, and I have no idea what the root cause might be.

Here's what I see when I try `curl https://mail.google.com` in PS:

```
curl : The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl https://mail.google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

This *only* happens with `mail.google.com` - all other domains are working just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening, or even what some good next steps are for debugging? In addition wanting to regain access to Gmail, I am also just genuinely curious to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue, or some other internet provider issue?

Comment: [What is a 502 Bad Gateway Error (And How Can I Fix It)?](https://www.howtogeek.com/356389/what-is-a-502-bad-gateway-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/)

Comment: @DavidPostill no luck on any of those fixes. It's across all browsers, and changing my DNS to Google DNS didn't fix it.

Comment: You might try CloudFlare DNS: https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/ . If that doesn't work, then most likely it's your ISP. You can verify by trying to connect through your ISP with another device, or by taking your PC to a public SIP, e.g. library or coffee shop.

Comment: I don't know what's happening, but personally I would at least try to connect via your mobile phone, i.e. making the phone a wi-fi hotspot and connect through that, still using the computer. Then you could verify if the connection matters (whether it's your ISP or not), and get closer to an identification of the problem. I would also try to log in with a different Google account, as it could be a problem on Google's side connected to that specific account. If you have a VPN you could also try to connect via that (or use a free one like the one in the Opera browser).

Comment: I'm just throwing in ideas of what I would do just to get closer to an identification of the problem. I would also try in an incognito browser window to see if it works when there are no previous cookies in the browser.